# Remove css admin template from component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I'm designing a custom component where I am utilising the `tmpl=component` ability to render the component only rather than displaying the default template.
How can I remove the unwanted css files which are creating a styling conflict, from the site's head, within the component ?

I use this codes and insert after defined('_JEXEC') or die;

```
         //get the array containing all the script declarations
     $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
     $headData = $document->getHeadData();
     $styles = $headData['styles'];

     //remove your script, i.e. mootools
     unset($styles['/administrator/templates/isis/css/template-rtl.css']);

     $headData['styles'] = $styles;
     $document->setHeadData($headData);
```

and this code

```
unset($this->item->_styles[JURI::root(true) . '/administrator/templates/isis/css/template-rtl.css']);
```

but , these code not work

I want to delete `administrator/templates/isis/css/template-rtl.css` from custom component source and head.

A Screenshot from custom component source
[image]

Comment: It looks like you found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073452/2943403 How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416287/2943403 And these might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040849/2943403 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647194/2943403  (and if it's inexplicably Head trouble: https://www.danielhpavey.uk/joomla/remove-individual-joomla-stylesheets-and-javascript-from-header)

Comment: @mickmackusa these code and method not work at component ,, just worked at template ,,, but i want remove stylesheet head file at componnet

Comment: Let's try to get some diagnostic feedback flowing: `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(json_encode($document->getHeadData()), 'info');`  Does this give us any clues?

Comment: @mickmackusa JS CSS Control plugin works perfectly
setting description
CSS File : /administrator/templates/isis/css/template-rtl.css
Limit Excecution : option=com_payamak
Backend Execution : yes
but when inseert above code at views tmpl component file , cant remove css file

Comment: Eorisis looks like a non-free download.  https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/eorisis-jquery/  It was mentioned in my first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The component is rendered *before* the template is parsed. You're trying to remove assets which haven't been added yet. You would need a system plugin to remove template stylesheets.

Comment: So this 9 year old tutorial is simply incorrect? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.gavick.com/blog/disable-css-style-joomla/amp Was this ever true?

Comment: @mickmackusa The tutorial is correct. But it's for removing component and module assets using a code snippet placed in the template. Not the other way around.